# Connect to GCP Cloud SQL from Compute Engine (not from App Engine)

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Typical issues for teams that are migrating from AWS to GCP. How to properly connect to Cloud SQL from Compute engine.

In short that what you [should know](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features) about Cloud SQL service at GCP. 
As I see SQL Cloud more API rather clean MySQL socket tend to work with App Engine rather as plain DB.

[List of options](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods?hl=en_US) that you have to validate and use Cloud SQL without involving developers:

- [Connection using mysql-client or SQL protocol](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) from external machine or even from Compute Engine requires to add your IP to whitelist. Keep in mind that Compute Engine you will be forced to use static IP due security limitations.In production you [should use IP address with SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance)
- To validate connection from Compute Engine you should use Cloud Shell and gcloud utility
  `gcloud sql connect [INSTANCE_ID] --user=root`
- Other option that works only with Second Generation of instances and can be (should be) used in production is [SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy) that should be installed on client Compute engine and run as service. You need:

  - Enable SQL Cloud API
  - Create and use Service Account with MySQL Client permissions for your instance
  - Install and run SQL Proxy
  - Connect to `localhost` to use proxy as bridge to your SQL Cloud Instance

As result there open questions about "best practices" for production use:

1. How to automate it in the way that new instances in autoscaling group would be able to connect to Cloud SQL after start? My approach: create template that will start SQL Proxy as service. Is there another way?
2. How to connect to multiple Cloud SQL instances form the same Compute Engine?

Comment: A single Cloud SQL proxy process can proxy connections for multiple instances.

Comment: Using Google Cloud SQL with Compute Engine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkqnNVk9jEU

Comment: @dagang not very good solution for autoscaling and multiple group  due "Keep in mind that Compute Engine you will be forced to use static IP due security limitations.In production you should use IP address with SSL" All instances must have static IP's

Comment: @Vadim using multiple sql-proxy agents on different ports? Or there an option to link specific instances to specific alias?

Comment: When using the proxy you have the option of either using TCP ports or (named) UNIX sockets. If using TCP ports, you would have one port per instance, if using UNIX sockets you would just use the instance connection name.

Comment: @vadim actually that great idea but in case of Windows it wouldn't work.

Comment: On Windows, you would use one TCP port per instance.

Comment: There's also a GUI way to connect if you're using a 2nd gen GCloud SQL instance.
You first get the external IP of your compute engine and include it in the Authorizations tab of your GCloud SQL dashboard. Here's a quick video: https://youtu.be/mvIE8LkXEEY